# Is JAVA necessary for android development?

Tags: java, android

I know C, C++, javascript and most web languages like php,ruby etc.. and web frameworks.

I am a little bit aware of eclipse ide for javascript and c/c++ developers, so are they having equivalent control as of java?

And is eclipse the only ide available for android development?

Comment: I've made an android app and 90% of it was Java, so I think it's pretty important.

Comment: No, not at all. No, Eclipse is on its way out actually. You can use any IDE you want, but recently Google introduced Android Studio (which is based on the community edition of IntelliJ, which is awesome, but still not stable since it's still just the preview edition)

Comment: What kind of application do you want to make? Java may be the default, but some applications are more easily done in one language than another.

Comment: You can write a web application that supports Dekstops, iOS and Android.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Java is the *standard* way of writing Android apps, but it's not strictly *necessary*. For example, there's also [Xamarin.Android](http://xamarin.com/android) which lets you write Android apps in C# - although it will still fire up a Dalvik VM behind the scenes, as the Android "native" controls are in Java. Using Java is probably the simplest option. To use other languages and still take advantage of the native controls, you'll need to find some kind of bridge (in the same way that Xamarin.Android is a bridge) - and you may not find it's available in the language you prefer.

Additionally, you'll find pretty much all the examples and tutorials for Android are written in Java, so it's lower friction in that sense too.

As for IDEs, you don't have to use Eclipse - I believe that [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) (currently in preview) is based on IntelliJ.

Comment: too lucky to receive answer from you Jon. Thanks,i was struggling for this, i just started looking at the java tutorials and looks like will finish this weekend. Thanks

Comment: Yes, Android Studio is based on IntelliJ, but it's only in a preview state right now (version 0.3.2)

Comment: @Ridcully: Thanks, will edit for that.

Answer (score 1):

A large portion of Java libraries is supported in Android. Therefore, it can be said that Android development is java-based.

But there are lots of alternative. It's not needed to know java to develop android application. If you are C/C++ developer, you can check out [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Java is not compulsory, but preferable.
As you are comfortable with web scripts, better use [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) framework.
It allows you to write code in html, javascript and css, which can be then used to make Android/iOS/Windows applications. Such apps are called web-apps.

It needs just a bit of java to make the application work.

Having said this, if you code in java, applications could be more responsive. Such apps are called native-apps.

Here are some [phonegap plug-ins](https://github.com/thechaithanya/phonegap-plugins).

Answer (score 0):

Java is preferred but C#/C++ can also be used. 
http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [Phonegap](http://phonegap.com/) to build an Multiplatform application(iOs,android,Win7/8,Blackberry,tizen) using simple Js,html and css
2. You can use [Xamarin](http://xamarin.com/?gclid=CIXlmYTL4bsCFVFU4godrBsAfw) for same purpose using simple C# and asp.net

Possible IDE's :

```
1. Visual Studio
2. Eclipse
3. Android Studio
```